# Save a combionation of string and matrix in cell over loop iterations MATLAB

Tags: matlab, save, cell

I have the example below:

```
dirname1='CCB2456788'
 Result1=[1 2 3;
         4 5 6]


 dirname2='989gh67878'

 result2=[23 5 ; 1 4]

 ......
```

For every single dataset, I would like to create a cell and store all the info into it and the data of the all the subject in a bigger cell. Do you have any suggestion how can I do it?

Comment: Have you created dynamic variables? 

Comment: Yes.. I have some dynamic variables that make those small matrixes that you can see. but I don't know how to save it in each iteration

Comment: You should not create them in the first place.

Comment: Where exactly are you having difficulty? Have you read how to create cell arrays in the MATLAB documentation? Have you attempted any code? Also, I notice that you've not accepted any of the answers to your previous questions. You might do that, if an answer has solved your question, as it gives others incentive to answer your future questions.

Comment: @beaker: I accepted those ones that looked useful. for example your answer is not useful therefore I won't accept it. Thank you :)

Comment: @sardar: in each iteration, I would have a new dirname and a new result I would like to associate one cell to all the information of one subject and having subcells for more detail information

Comment: From now on? You should consider revisiting your older questions and marking the best answers that solve your problem as accepted and upvoting the other helpful answers

Comment: Do not create new `dirname*` and `result*` variables in each iteration. Store them directly in  a pre-allocated cell

Comment: @sardar: I can not avoid to do it. as I don't want to mix up the results for different subjects. what  you are proposing me is not a solution

Comment: That's not mixing up. If you think that you cannot avoid, you need to think again. There is never a reason to create dynamic variables.  By a cell array, the index of the cell array already indicates the subject ( or whatever) . You'd be having `dirname{1}` instead of `dirname1` and so on and your code won't smell

Comment: if I have 100 subjects I would like to have 100 cells but each cell needs to have 3 subcells, patient identification, and result of the analysis. I know how to create cells but I don't know what to do with subcells considering results for each subject have different size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159527/discussion-between-juliette-and-sardar-usama).